# MVC Submit for Approval System

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

So , My ASP.Net MVC Application(.net 4.5) has 3 Tables(SQL Server).
Listings(key LID) , Details(foreign key LID) , Locations(foreign key LID).

As far as the application goes, any registered user can enter a listing into the database. I need some facility to moderate the data before it goes live...How do I achieve this?

As soon as the user submits a piece of data, it shouldn't go live but must wait for the approval of an Admin after which it gets visible on to the site.

Comment: I would add a bool to the Listings table called something like approved and default it to false on creation. Then an administrator could go in and look at all the recently created listings that are still marked as false. Once approved  you update that record's approved column to true.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a status field in the Listing model. When listings are entered they are marked with one status like "unapproved". When an admin reviews them, they will mark them as "approved". On your user interface you will only show listings that are status == approved.

This is all assuming you have user management and roles already defined so that users can be defined as non-admin and admin roles.

Comment: I thought of the same thing , but then if there is problematic database entry would'nt it be effecting the entire main db table ?? @Chris

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Sql a bit column called [IsApproved] (True | False) should suffice for this. You can then reflect that flag in your model so when you load the data you can make sure you exclude the results that are not yet approved.

You'd need some form of administrator approval, either through an MVC page or just by changing the flag in the database to True yourself

When you load your model (depending on how your querying the DB), you can then just request `myTable.Where(x => x.IsApproved).ToList()` to return the approved results to your view.

Comment: Yes , but giving access to the user(who is going to be random) access to enter into my main database would'nt pose a security threat ? @Joey

Comment: @MukeshMurugan try not to confuse the app with your database, if you want to restrict who can access your MVC application you need to think about the types of authentication to implement (Windows, Forms, Digest etc...) if you happy for people to add new items through your form to persist that information to your database (but require approval) then you don't need authentication. You can hide the [IsApproved] attribute from your MVC View, and have it as a database only flag. You database connection should be secured in your app.config, something the user cannot see.